# If $f(s)T(s)=a$ prove $\gamma (s) $ is a straight line

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a curve with parameterized of arc length, and we suppose that for the tangent vector $T(S)$ of $\gamma(s)$ there exist a function $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(s)T(s)=a$ for some non-zero vector $a$ , prove the curve is a straight line.

I tried to take the derivative and show $k=0$ (where $k$ is the curvature of a curve )

using Frenet's formulas we have that ${f}(s)'T(s)+f(s)kN(s)=0$ but i am stuck how to show that $k=0$

any hints.

Comment: Do we know that $f$ is differentiable? A more elementary argument might be in order. Observe that $1 = |T(s)| = \frac{|a|}{|f(s)|}$, so that $|f(s)| = |a|$. Thus $f(s) = \pm |a|$. If $f$ is not constant, then $T$ cannot be continuous. So, as long as we assume $T$ is continuous, we must have that $f$ is constant, from which it follows that $T$ is constant.

Comment: Good observation we do not know if f is differentiable, but I guess we can show it as you write above.

Comment: Why are we differentiating? Either $T=a/\|a\|$ or $T=-a/\|a\|$. Either way, $T$ is constant and ¥\gamma$ is a portion of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $T(s)$ and $N(s)$ are perpendicular, hence linearly independent. Thus
$$
f'(s) T(s) + f(s) k N(s) = 0
$$
implies
$$
f'(s) = 0 \, ;  \quad f(s) k = 0
$$
Since $f'(s) = 0$ for all $s$, we may set $f(s) = C$. Thus $Ck = 0$. Since $a \neq 0$, we may not have $C = 0$. Therefore, $k = 0$.